# Simple EF 5 Query brings back no results

Tags: entity-framework

Strange issue:

Trying to do a simple query against my email notifications table:

```
        using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
        {
            IQueryable<EmailNotification> query = context.EmailNotifications.Where(q => (q.LastSendAttemptStatus == EmailNotificationSendStatuses.Pending) || (q.LastSendAttemptStatus == EmailNotificationSendStatuses.Resend));

            return query.ToList();
        }
```

It brings back no results even though the rows are there. In fact, I looked at the SQL it generates and ran it without any changes, and it **does** bring the right results.

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[EmailNotificationID] AS [EmailNotificationID], 
[Extent1].[From] AS [From], 
[Extent1].[To] AS [To], 
[Extent1].[Cc] AS [Cc], 
[Extent1].[Bcc] AS [Bcc], 
[Extent1].[Subject] AS [Subject], 
[Extent1].[Body] AS [Body], 
[Extent1].[LastSendAttemptOn] AS [LastSendAttemptOn], 
[Extent1].[LastSendAttemptStatus] AS [LastSendAttemptStatus], 
[Extent1].[FailureComments] AS [FailureComments]
FROM [dbo].[EmailNotifications] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (0 =  CAST( [Extent1].[LastSendAttemptStatus] AS int)) OR (3 =  CAST( [Extent1].   [LastSendAttemptStatus] AS int))
```

Any hints on what should I be checking?

Comment: Have you changed the table definition - do you need to rebuild your edmx file? If you debug, can you enumerate through the result manually?

Comment: This is code first so no edmx file involved. There are no results to enumerate. No change in entity.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this. It turned out to be a connection string issue.

Comment: he probably cant just yet. but yes, please close when possible